# How to slice text string so it takes X number of words after number?

Tags: r, string

I'm using R to process some inconsistently formatted text data. Here is a sample of my address data, which is stored in a column called "address".

```
dispatchid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
address <- c("123 test st", "in front of 456 second st", "across the parking lot of 123 fourty one ave east","678 fourth ave w", "hospital, back entrance, 890 fifth road east", "123 sixth blvd apartment 111")
data <- data.frame(dispatchid, address)
```

As you can see, some rows will just have the address stored like rows 1 and 4. Other rows have other information in front of the address.

What I want to do is to extract just the address portion, so that my result will look like this:

```
dispatchid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
address <- c("123 test st", "456 second st", "123 fourty one ave east","678 fourth ave w", "890 fifth road east", "123 sixth blvd")
data <- data.frame(dispatchid, address)
```

I thought I could make use of the word(), using the code below, but it only gives me the first 4 words. This doesn't work addresses where there's a lot of pre-text in front o the actual address (i.e. row 5).

```
word(data$address, start = 1, end = 4, sep = " "))
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the solutions. The only case that isn't solved is the record in row 6, for example, where there is text after the address. However, I've tested all of the solutions and they all get me close enough to my goal. I think I can tack on the words() code that i have earlier and run a second step to drop everything after the 4th word, Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Use `sub` to delete all the non-digits from the beginning of the string:

```
data$address <- sub("^\\D+", "", data$address)
data
  dispatchid                      address
1          1                  123 test st
2          2                456 second st
3          3      123 fourty one ave east
4          4             678 fourth ave w
5          5          890 fifth road east
6          6 123 sixth blvd apartment 111
```

Comment: Much simpler than mine, upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of regular expressions to extract the desired part of the string. In this case, you could use a regular expression indicating to extract the part of the string that starts with numbers (`\\d+`), followed by anything (`.+`) and ends at the end of the string (`$`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data |>
  mutate(newaddress = str_extract(address, "\\d+.+$"))

#  dispatchid                                           address                   #newaddress
#1          1                                       123 test st                  123 test st
#2          2                         in front of 456 second st                456 second st
#3          3 across the parking lot of 123 fourty one ave east      123 fourty one ave east
#4          4                                  678 fourth ave w             678 fourth ave w
#5          5      hospital, back entrance, 890 fifth road east          890 fifth road east
#6          6                      123 sixth blvd apartment 111 123 sixth blvd apartment 111
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
dispatchid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
address <- c("123 test st", "in front of 456 second st", "across the parking lot of 123 fourty one ave east","678 fourth ave w", "hospital, back entrance, 890 fifth road east", "123 sixth blvd apartment 111")
data <- data.frame(dispatchid, address)

sub("^[^\\d]* (\\d+.*$)", "\\1", data$address)
#> [1] "123 test st"                  "456 second st"               
#> [3] "123 fourty one ave east"      "678 fourth ave w"            
#> [5] "890 fifth road east"          "123 sixth blvd apartment 111"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Regex explanation:

- `"^"` beginning of string;
- `"^[^\\d]*"` at the beginning of the string, find any character but a digit zero or more times;
- `"\\d+.*$` a digit one or more times followed by any character zero or more times until the end of the string;
- `"^[^\\d]* (\\d+.*$)"` both patterns above separated by a space character. The 2nd pattern is the first capture group, since it is between parenthesis.

If this regex finds anything and replaces it by the first capture group `"\\1"`, then it will only keep the sub-string starting with the 1st digit and ending in the end of the input string.